# What is the Krull dimension of $A[x,y,z]/\langle xy,xz \rangle$

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension

What is the Krull dimension of $B=A[x,y,z]/\langle xy,xz \rangle$, given that $A$ is a Noetherian commutative ring?

Comment: It depends on the ring $A$. Are you supposing that $A$ is a field?

Comment: i am looking for the dimension in terms of the dimension of A

Comment: Intuition says it's $1$ more than the dimension of $A$. The three variables increase the dimension by $3$, and the two-generator ideal subtracts two from the dimension again.

Comment: If $B$ is your ring, then $B/(x)=A[y,z]$, so $\dim B\geq\dim A+2$, and eequality holds when $A$ is a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that $$\dim B=\sup\{\dim B/P:P\text{ minimal prime}\}.$$

Let $P$ be a minimal prime of $B$. Then $P=\mathfrak p/(XY,XZ)$ with $\mathfrak p$ prime in $A[X,Y,Z]$ minimal over $(XY,XZ)$. Then $\mathfrak p$ is minimal over $(X)$ or $\mathfrak p$ is minimal over $(Y,Z)$. Conversely, every minimal prime over $(X)$, respectively $(Y,Z)$ gives rise to a minimal prime of $B$.

Then $$\dim B=\sup(\dim A[X,Y,Z]/(X),\dim A[X,Y,Z]/(Y,Z))=\sup(\dim A[Y,Z],\dim A[X])=\sup(\dim A+2,\dim A+1)=\dim A+2.$$

Comment: In the above proof why should $\mathfrak{p}$ be minimal over (X) or (Y,Z)?

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is precisely $\dim A+2$. We have $\dim B\geq\dim B/x=\dim A+2$. On the other hand, since any prime ideal of $B$ must either contain $x$ or both $y,z$, one can check that the above inequality is actually an equality.